# MAMP Pro: How to connect to MySql server on Mac OS via Network?

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

I have a PC with Mac OS 10.6 that is running as Webserver on LAN. I use MAMP Pro for that (Apache + MySql).

Today, I have problem that: From other PC on LAN, I try to connect to Mysql server on Mac and the error occurred:

**2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.10' (10061)**

I make sure uncheck "Allow local access only" on tab MySql on MAMP Pro and firewall is turn off.

I try use nmap to scan the webserver and the port 3306 is not listed in result.

Hope someone can help !

Thanks !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default MySQL is limited to connect only to localhost (127.0.0.1) because of some security reason. if you want to remote access your MySQL you need to edit a default my.cnf value

open my.cnf file which is located in

> Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my.cnf

and edit the following

> bind-address = 127.0.0.1

to

> bind-address = 0.0.0.0

save the file and restart mysql server by typing the following command in your terminal

> sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart

your MySQL server should now be able to access over the network. to verify it is listening to all interface type the following in your terminal

```
netstat -anp | grep 3306
```

and if you see the following in response it means it is working

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     -
```

the above information is taken from this link : http://rclermont.blogspot.in/2008/05/configuring-mysql-for-network-access.html

hope this helps

Comment: It's not work for me because when I start/stop MAMP, the 0.0.0.0 will be reset to 127.0.0.1 by MAMP.

Comment: Make sure you make the changes while in administrator account

Comment: Open MAMP Pro, click File menu > Edit Template > MySQL my.cnf.

Comment: how to do it if we have MAMP (not PRO) ?

Comment: @mezod the instructions is for MAMP, try editing your bind-address value located in `Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: MAMP doesn't come with a my.cnf by default, you can create it yourself though... I was trying to connect using the wrong port, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I was following Ibrahim answer but the file is no longer in that path. I ran the following command in mac mojave

```
$ mdfind -name my.cnf
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf
$ vim /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

Then made the change

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```